# What is a more formal way to phrase, "but I'm not talking about [something]"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing an essay, and I need a way to say "but I'm not talking about [something], I'm talking about [something]." In other words, I need a way to acknowledge something misleading and clarify it in some other way.

Comment: Footnotes can be useful for this.

Comment: Er... maybe "[something] notwithstanding"?

Comment: “But [first context] aside …”

Answer (score 1):

> In this case/essay I won't be focusing on [something] but instead the [other
>   thing]

...but its really impossible to give a sentence without any context